# Simulate the http 503 status with tomcat and spring

Tags: spring, http, tomcat

I'm tryng to simulate the http 503 status within my spring application and tomcat. So I created a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/503", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String error(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final ModelMap model)
{

    response.setStatus(503);
    return null;
}
```

and in the web xml I set up the filter:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/errorpages/simple503.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

When I call the /503 controller is showe the tipical 503 tomcat page (no the one i would like to show) and is called my 404 controller.

I suppose that this is cause by the return null in the 503 controller... So what can I do to return my error page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can (assuming your view handler recognizes the string):

```
return "errorpages/simple503";
```

And annotate your controller method with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)`